# Sencha List Not displaying

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

```
Ext.define('myapp.view.alerts.Alerts', {
    extend : 'Ext.List',
    fullscreen: true,
    itemTpl: '{title}',
    data: [
        { title: 'Item 1' },
        { title: 'Item 2' },
        { title: 'Item 3' },
        { title: 'Item 4' }
    ]
});
```

The list gets displayed, but not text inside them. Why is this happening? This is the exaple from Sencha Docs. http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example, they are using `Ext.create`, meaning they can pass the config options directly. You, on the other hand, *extend* the class, so you must put overridden config options in the `config`, not the root:

```
Ext.define('myapp.view.alerts.Alerts', {
    extend : 'Ext.List',
    config: {
        fullscreen: true,
        itemTpl: '{title}',
        data: [
            { title: 'Item 1' },
            { title: 'Item 2' },
            { title: 'Item 3' },
            { title: 'Item 4' }
        ]
    }
});
```